Not possible to print the Pipe character as a delimiter in our report
I have an old application and the reports generated in 1999.
It was possible to print the report in right format and structure on a specific PC and specific printer but after moving to another place the PC and the printer are changed and after these changes the report couldn't be printed out correctly same as before.
The statistics of the report are correct, but the print format doesn't have tabular.
The delimiter and table maker is a "Pipe character" but I think the different between report generator code page and windows is the cause of this problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If the application is dos based, try using it in Dosbox, and ensure you have the correct codepage set in the config.

It utilizes a virtual DOS automatically, however, I am uncertain about the proper procedure for setting the appropriate code page and identifying the appropriate code page.

on the working machine, open command prompt, and type mode con do the same on the not working machine, and compare. If the codepage is different, use mode con cp select=437 to change. (change 437 to whatever it must be)

I will do it and answer you the result.

Both of machines have a same code page also cp437.

Both of machines have a same code page also cp437. I think I should set the printer's code page because it prints only the raw data and couldn't print the drawing table characters. I don't know how could I set the printer code page, and I am not sure if the problem is from code page setting in the printer.
